# How to install specific version of Azure CLI in Linux RHEL

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

We can use below command to install azure cli on Linux:

curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash

But what if we want to install a specific version of azure cli lets say version 2.0.23 as 2.0.24 has some issue

Please Help!

Comment: Also please note that when we use that command it installs latest available version of azure cli which is 2.0.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **RPM package** to install it.

We can find the release [here](https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli/):

[image]

Download it to your Linux, then use `rpm` command to install it.

---

**Update**:

Thanks for Anil Kumar P share, we can use this command to install Azure CLI:

> yum install azure-cli-2.0.23-1.el7.x86_64

Comment: Thanks Jason. Will try installing it this way. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Hi jason, This solution works too i guess. But we had raised one more ticket with azure and got a simpler solution as well:) we can use below command straight away

Comment: yum install azure-cli-2.0.23-1.el7.x86_64

Comment: @AnilKumarP Thank you for your share, I will add that to my answer, it will help others:)

Comment: :) Thanks for your quick responses Jason :)

Comment: Is there is list of version for ubuntu also apt or pip ?

Answer (score 1):

There is another way you can install and lock the version of CLI.  Say you want to install 2.0.38 on Ubuntu 16.04:

`sudo apt-get install -y azure-cli=2.0.38-1~xenial
echo azure-cli hold | sudo dpkg --set-selection
sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the complete list of versions for different distros: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/dists/

E.g Azure CLI versions for Ubuntu 
https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages

```
Package: azure-cli
Priority: extra
Section: python
Installed-Size: 317827
Maintainer: Azure Python CLI Team <azpycli@microsoft.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 2.0.41-1~xenial
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3)
Filename: pool/main/a/azure-cli/azure-cli_2.0.41-1~xenial_all.deb
Size: 40889424
MD5sum: cc807f4010b6af9507d74ef5404ee09c
SHA1: f593bffa3731a3a670b927723ca97071b0166471
SHA256: 5cfa52a187ac7d028c663f16c4bfea7ac7e49e5917cf90fe3a0299eaa496a194
SHA512: 384bf978379616522405d9e3e25645243c8c8529cd675c7bd036b8817f9220c2cdf3c1a6c3660f23f5775eeffab740608d678c5508b6aeca0359fc4370f84c74
Description: Azure CLI 2.0
 A great cloud needs great tools; we're excited to introduce Azure CLI 2.0,
 our next generation multi-platform command line experience for Azure.
Homepage: https://github.com/azure/azure-cli

Package: azure-cli
Priority: extra
Section: python
Installed-Size: 314381
Maintainer: Azure Python CLI Team <azpycli@microsoft.com>
Architecture: all
**Version: 2.0.38-1~xenial**
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3)
Filename: pool/main/a/azure-cli/azure-cli_2.0.38-1~xenial_all.deb
Size: 40504494
MD5sum: 7f076d5a7cbc38ab02913c73b2f2c372
SHA1: 10e1460570c72a1a28908c0ed73520e5ccd43a99
SHA256: c127e448b21c746c7bb67e8ab5074802458aaeb84516f746c25463fa20f45b1b
SHA512: 0969e2260ee48401df3796c26b682a8fb39b1a5d7bf5f7c9613a102dfcf3052d362cf93664317f8f4e035efa673c77316009d15d76ef8b378b829cec43f1836f
Description: Azure CLI 2.0
 A great cloud needs great tools; we're excited to introduce Azure CLI 2.0,
 our next generation multi-platform command line experience for Azure.
Homepage: https://github.com/azure/azure-cli
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to switch to previous version of azure-cli and your answer was really helpful!